# Plotting a geopandas dataframe using plotly

Tags: python, plotly, geopandas

I have a geopandas dataframe, which consists of the region name(**District**), the **geometry** column, and the **amount** column. My goal is to plot a choropleth map using the method mentioned below
https://plotly.com/python/choropleth-maps/#using-geopandas-data-frames

Here’s a snippet of my dataframe

[image]

I also checked that my columns were in the right format/type.

[image]

And here's the code I used to plot the map

```
fig = px.choropleth(merged,

                   geojson=merged.geometry,

                   locations=merged.index,

                   color="Amount")

fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=False)

fig.show()
```

It produced the below figure

[image]

which is obviously not the right figure. For some reasons, it doesn't show the map, instead it shows a line and when I zoom in, I am able to see the map but it has lines running through it. Like this

[image]

Has anyone ran into a similar problem? If so how were you able to resolve it?

The Plotly version I am using is 4.7.0. I have tried upgrading to a most recent version but it still didn’t work.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Please find my code and the data on my [github](https://github.com/justenyirimana/plotly-geopandas).

Comment: I checked the same result with `px.choropleth_mapbox()`. The map was displayed, but it was not filled by region. I have checked the geometry data, is it in latitude and longitude values? I checked the data from the official [reference page](https://plotly.com/python/mapbox-county-choropleth/).

Comment: @r-beginners The data has a geometry column which holds the polygons/shape for each region. I have updated my question to show the Dtype for each column.

Comment: Doesn't the actual data represent latitude and longitude, not the data type?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I get your question.

Comment: What I wanted to make sure is that this data is correct? `POLYGON ((498847.140 4793516.119, 498839.366 4...` My understanding is that I need the latitude and longitude information.

Comment: Yes, the data is correct because I am able to produce a choropleth map using matplotlib but not with plotly.

Comment: What @r-beginners is saying, is you should try to reproject your GeoDataFrame into WGS84 first. For instance, gdf.to_crs(pyproj.CRS.from_epsg(4326), inplace=True). All examples on the web seems to use geodataframes in this projection which isn't unexpected... Note that matplotlib is only a canvas, so you won't have any trouble plotting your dataframe whatever your projection is.

Comment: @tgrandje, after projecting the geodataframe into the WGS84, I am now able to render the map. Do you want to post the answer and then I will mark it as the correct answer?

Comment: I'll leave it to @r-beginners who deserves it !

Comment: Great, @r-beginners, please go ahead and post the answer.

Comment: @Poopah, you can post your own answer. That's the best way to go.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I'll give you the answer to @tgrandje's comment that solved the problem. Thanks to @Poopah and @tgrandje for the opportunity to raise the answer.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import geopandas as gpd
import pyproj

# reading in the shapefile
fp = "./data/"
map_df = gpd.read_file(fp)
map_df.to_crs(pyproj.CRS.from_epsg(4326), inplace=True)

df = pd.read_csv("./data/loans_amount.csv")
# join the geodataframe with the cleaned up csv dataframe
merged = map_df.set_index('District').join(df.set_index('District'))
#merged = merged.reset_index()
merged.head()

fig = px.choropleth(merged, geojson=merged.geometry, locations=merged.index, color="Amount")
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=False)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another possible source of the problem (when using Plotly graph_objects) is mentioned in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/436649/209400) over at gis.stackexchange.com:

1. The `locations` argument has to point to a column that matches GeoJSON's 'id's.
2. The `geojson` argument expects a dictionary.

> To solve your problem, you should: (i) point locations to the dataframe's index, and (ii) turn your GeoJSON string to a dictionary.

It's not exactly the answer to your question, but I thought my problem was the same as yours and this helped me. So I am including the answer here.